# Segmentation fault while trying to draw triangles with C

Tags: c, for-loop, malloc

Continuing on a previous question in a previous thread:

Hi guys! Part 2 of my bouncing ball questions. ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267814/using-malloc-on-structs-arrays-in-other-files))

I'm still getting a segmentation fault in my code, but only while drawing the last element of an array. I have put in print-statements to see exactly where the code stops, and it is in the last iteration in the for loop below:

```
void draw_object(object_t *object)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < object->numtriangles; i++) {
        /* Translate triangle into middle of screen before drawing it */
        object->model[i].tx = object->surface->w/2;
        object->model[i].ty = object->surface->h/2;


        /* Set new rotation and scale it down */
        object->model[i].rotation = object->rotation;
        object->model[i].scale = object->scale;

        /* And draw it */
        draw_triangle(object->surface, &object->model[i]);
        printf("ok\n %d", i+1);
    }
```

Now there are 478 elements in the group and it goes through 477 before the segmentation fault appears. If I change the second condition in the for loop to something like this:

```
for(int i=0, i<200, i++)
```

The segmentation fault appears after 199 iterations.
I have no idea why this is happening. I would think it is very unlikely that I run out of memory, especially when I can do 400 iterations without a problem until the last iteration.

All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, which it looks like you are, it will tell you where.

Comment: I see no problems in the code presented, there's probably UB elsewhere.

Comment: Can't tell without a [mcve].

Comment: "after 199 iterations"?! if your loop ending condition is `<200`, the **200th** iteration will print 199! Are you sure?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I originally had     printf("%d", i) and it got to 198. And also when the number was 478 it stopped at 476. (Later on I added I+1 in the print statement and it still stops at the last iteration.)

Comment: OK. Then notice that the output is *line-buffered*, so it would print `198 ok\n` - and then 199 would remain in the buffer. Add `fflush(stdout);` or `\n` at the end of the printf, and you'd notice that it totally doesn't crash there. Also, now would be a good time to learn to use a proper debugger!

Comment: I'll try with the valgrind program that @dbush suggested! Thanks anyway for the tip wit /n. Turns out it stops after the for loop, but still within the function since I get no printed statements from the main function, where I have put a print statement to test wether or not the code continues after draw_object is called.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you're printing the number after the newline? Why not `ok %d\n`?

Comment: @barmar Not really :) I changed quite quickly to what you're suggesting!